# Telegram Bot - Send Info message

Tags: api, telegram-bot, sendmessage

currently I am working to creating telegram bot. Now I required to know is there is any API to send info messages (like the one we get during a user is added r deleted in a group chat)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do detailed search, in case of issue then post out here

Comment: NitinSingh, I have posted the query here after doing detailed search for a day.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do can be done using answerCallbackQuery method.

But first of all you have to create a CallbackQuery using InlineKeyboardMarkup to create inline keyboards you can follow the steps in [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51820743/3929525)

After creating the callback query you have to answer it using one of the codes below:

```
if (update.CallbackQuery.Data == "CQ1")
{
 await Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Id,"Text",true,null, 0);
}
```

This way the message will look like a message box and will disappear after the user taps on OK. But if you use the code below, the message will show up and disappear automatically after a few seconds.

```
else if (update.CallbackQuery.Data == "CQ2")
{
 await Bot.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(update.CallbackQuery.Id, "Text", false,null, 30);
}
```

> By the way, messages that are shown at times like adding a user to a
> group are service messages and theses kinds of message can only be
> sent by telegram server.
>
> If my suggestion does not fix your issue you can use pinMessage method
> that sticks a single message to the top of the page in groups and
> channels. But note that you can only pin **one** message to a channel
> or group and for pinning another message firstly you should unpin the
> previous one.

Comment: This is not a solution. `answerCallbackQuery` displays a popup for couple of seconds and then disappears.

Comment: As I said you cannot send System Messages, because as it says they're sent by system and that's why I suggested an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to send such info messages.

And in my opinion, this feature is unlikely to be added in future because:

- info messages usually tell you  information about your chat; they are managed by telegram servers
- therefore they should not be sent by [`User`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user)s
- bot is an instance of `User`